# Not able to access SavedStateHandle from @Hilt ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

I have two fragments, and I want to access the **todoId** from the ViewModel of the second fragment, but I am encountering issues while trying to access it.

Here is the problem I am facing:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.todolist, PID: 14933
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.todolist.ui.add_edit_todo.AddEditTodoViewModel.<init>(AddEditTodoViewModel.kt:33)
        at com.test.todolist.util.DaggerTodoApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerTodoApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:455)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:104)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:89)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:116)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
        at com.test.todolist.ui.add_edit_todo.AddEditTodoFragment.getViewModel(AddEditTodoFragment.kt:21)
        at com.test.todolist.ui.add_edit_todo.AddEditTodoFragment.onCreateView(AddEditTodoFragment.kt:42)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8381)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

1st fragment

```kotlin
package com.test.todolist.ui.todo_list

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.NavArgument
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.test.todolist.R
import com.test.todolist.databinding.FragmentTodoListBinding
import com.test.todolist.ui.todo_list.adapter.TodoAdapter
import com.test.todolist.util.UiEvent
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class TodoListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTodoListBinding
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<TodoListViewModel>()
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentTodoListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            viewModel.uiEvent.collect() { event ->
                when (event) {
                    is UiEvent.ShowSnackBar -> {
                        showSnackBar(event.message, event.action)
                    }
                    is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                        navigate(event.route, event.todoId)
                    }
                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
        }

        binding.fabAdd.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onEvent(TodoListEvents.OnAddTodoClick) }

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            viewModel.todo.collect() { todoList ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    binding.rvTodoList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                    binding.rvTodoList.adapter = TodoAdapter(requireContext(), todoList, viewModel)
                }
            }
        }



        return binding.root
    }

    private fun navigate(route: String, todoId: Int?) {
        val argument = Bundle()
        val id: Int = todoId ?: -1
        argument.putInt("todoId", id)
        navController.navigate(R.id.addEditTodoFragment, argument)
    }

    private fun showSnackBar(message: String, action: String?) {
        val snackBar = Snackbar
            .make(binding.root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setAction(action) {
                viewModel.onEvent(TodoListEvents.OnUndoDeleteClick)
            }

        snackBar.show()
    }
}
```

1st fragment ViewModel

```kotlin
package com.test.todolist.ui.todo_list

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.test.todolist.data.entity.Todo
import com.test.todolist.data.repository.TodoRepository
import com.test.todolist.util.Routes
import com.test.todolist.util.UiEvent
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.receiveAsFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class TodoListViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TodoRepository): ViewModel() {

    val todo = repository.getTodo()

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    private var deletedTodo: Todo? = null

    fun onEvent(events: TodoListEvents){
        when(events){
            is TodoListEvents.OnTodoClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(events.todo.id.toString()))
            }
            is TodoListEvents.DeleteTodo -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    deletedTodo = events.todo
                    repository.deleteTodo(events.todo)
                    sendUiEvent(UiEvent.ShowSnackBar("Todo deleted!", "Undo"))
                }
            }
            is TodoListEvents.OnDoneChange -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.insertTodo(events.todo.copy(isDone = events.isDone))
                }
            }
            is TodoListEvents.OnAddTodoClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(Routes.ADD_EDIT_TODO))
            }
            is TodoListEvents.OnUndoDeleteClick -> {
                deletedTodo?.let { todo ->
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        repository.insertTodo(todo)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(events: UiEvent){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(events)
        }
    }
}
```

2nd fragment

```kotlin
package com.test.todolist.ui.add_edit_todo

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.widget.doOnTextChanged
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.test.todolist.databinding.FragmentAddEditTodoBinding
import com.test.todolist.util.UiEvent
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class AddEditTodoFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddEditTodoBinding
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<AddEditTodoViewModel>()
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentAddEditTodoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            viewModel.uiEvent.collect { events ->
                when(events){
                    is UiEvent.ShowSnackBar -> {showSnackBar(events.message, events.action)}
                    is UiEvent.PopBackStack -> { navController.popBackStack()}
                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
        }

        binding.edtTitle.setText(viewModel.title)
        binding.edtDescription.setText(viewModel.description)

        binding.edtTitle.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTodoEvents.OnTitleChange(text.toString()))
        }
        binding.edtDescription.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTodoEvents.OnDescriptionChange(text.toString()))
        }
        binding.fabDone.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onEvent(AddEditTodoEvents.OnSaveTodoClick) }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun showSnackBar(message: String, action: String?){
        val snackBar = Snackbar
            .make(binding.root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        snackBar.show()
    }
}
```

2nd fragment ViewModel

```kotlin
package com.test.todolist.ui.add_edit_todo

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.test.todolist.data.entity.Todo
import com.test.todolist.data.repository.TodoRepository
import com.test.todolist.util.Routes
import com.test.todolist.util.UiEvent
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.receiveAsFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class AddEditTodoViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TodoRepository, savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel(){

    var todo by mutableStateOf<Todo?>(null)
        private set
    var title by mutableStateOf("")
        private set
    var description by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    init {
        val todoId = savedStateHandle.get<Int>("todoId")!!
        if (todoId != -1){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.getTodoById(todoId)?.let { todo ->
                    title = todo.title
                    description = todo.description ?: ""
                    this@AddEditTodoViewModel.todo = todo
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onEvent(events: AddEditTodoEvents){
        when(events){
            is AddEditTodoEvents.OnTitleChange -> { title = events.title}
            is AddEditTodoEvents.OnDescriptionChange -> { description = events.description}
            is AddEditTodoEvents.OnSaveTodoClick -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    if (title.isBlank()){
                        sendUiEvent(UiEvent.ShowSnackBar("The title can't be empty"))
                        return@launch
                    }
                    repository.insertTodo(Todo(id = todo?.id, title = title, description = description, isDone = todo?.isDone ?: false))
                    sendUiEvent(UiEvent.PopBackStack)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(events: UiEvent){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(events)
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle dependency

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //Room Database
    def room_version = "2.3.0" // check latest version from docs
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"

    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01'

    def nav_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

}
```

I am new to **MVVM** architecture and dependency injection using **Hilt**, which is why I am unable to identify the problem myself. I have tried searching for answers on StackOverflow, but none of them have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @AndroidEntryPoint annotation to all the views you create.If you are using the first activity when you open the project, you need to add @AndroidEntryPoint annotation to it.Next you need to create a reference class for Hilt. For example

- @HiltAndroidApp
  class HiltActivity : Application() { }

Then, just below the application tag in the manifest,

- android:name=".HiltActivity"

You need to define it. It should work now.
If you have any other questions, I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: I already done all of those steps. and its working fine if i am not accesing this `val todoId = savedStateHandle.get<Int>("todoId")!!` line of code. I am sharing my repo please check once [Link](https://github.com/ashifali3147/todo_list_mvvm/tree/nav_graph).